# Converting problematic Pandas columns values into JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the .xlsx file that has data from stocks values in polish currency PLN.
The head and all rows are as follows: Data,"Last","Opening","Max.","Min.","How many.","Change%".
But opening it with pd.read_excel() method, the dataframe has only one big column.

1. The date doesn't have values in quotes, and I don't know how to separate them properly into variables in Python
2. I want to create the json file with these variables, so that includes:

- date
- currency1 name, its value in this day
- currency2 name, its value in this day
- and so on.
  . How to make it properly, or should I iterate with some loops?

This is base code that I'm creating this file:

```
data_stocks = {}
data_stocks['stocks'] = []
data_stocks['stocks'].append({
'data': '01-01-2017',
'mWIG40': '0.0',
'sWIG80': '0.0',
'WIG': '0.0',
'WIG20': '0.0',
'WIG30': '0.0',
'CCCP': '0.0',
'CDR': '0.0',
'JSW': '0.0',
'PGE': '0.0',
'PKO': '0.0'
})

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data_stocks, outfile)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackOverflow. Could you provide an example of the dataframe with one big row + of you expected output ?

Comment: 30.12.2020,"3.989,45","4.000,93","4.000,93","3.978,66","5,38M","-0,28%" I want to get the first part as column so it contains date and the third part of opening stock price